# SQL: Query for getting records where one filed value exists more than one

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query, it has to fetch all records  where one of the field value  exists more than once,

Table will be like

```
S_NO    ID
S100    I01
S101    I01      
S102    I02
S103    I00
S104    I02
```

As some ID's exists more than once, result should be

```
S100  I01
S101  I01
S102  I02
S104  I02
```

Comment: can be you more specific on your question? what actually you want as result.?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: where ID 's exists more than once

Answer (score 5):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT S_NO,ID
FROM your_table
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM your_table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

***[SQLFIDLLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a750/3)***

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT id 
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Output:

```
| S_NO |  ID |
--------------
| S100 | I01 |
| S101 | I01 |
| S102 | I02 |
| S104 | I02 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff737/1)** demo